# mysql select distinct where count >1

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]Hello I am confused of the best way of achieving this. My query so far is below.

Basically at the moment I have an image that belongs to multiple media groups. What i want to bring back is a random media group for an image if a media group only has one image associated with it.

So for example if i have image 1,2,3

Image 1 belongs to media groups 10,11,12
Image 2 belongs to media groups 13,14,15
and Image three belongs to media groups 15,16,17

What i would like to bring back in this instance is

image 1 - media group 11
image 2 - media group 13
image 3 - media group 15

I would like image three to be 15 as 15 has two images associated with it so would want to bring this back. Please can you advise the best way of me achieving this desired result.

```
SELECT image_id, media_group_id, COUNT(*) as image_count FROM image_media_group
GROUP BY media_group_id
```

For example the above query brings back the below. I would not want to bring back image_id 1432 for every media group if there was only one image in the media group
My larger query for all results for media groups is as follows

```
SELECT T.guid_id, T.id, mg.name, mg.alias_title, T.title, T.hits, al.title, T.distance, uf.real_name, uf.user_name,mg.alias_title,
COUNT(1) as image_count
FROM 
     (SELECT imx.id,imx.distance, imx.guid_id, imx.user_id, imx.hits, imx.title, imx.visible, imx.approved, imx.advertise_to
      FROM image imx  
      ORDER BY floor(RAND()*(SELECT count(1) FROM image))      
     ) AS T        
INNER JOIN image_media_group img ON T.id = img.image_id 
INNER JOIN media_group_title mg ON img.media_group_id =mg.media_group_id
INNER JOIN album_image ai ON T.id = ai.image_id
INNER JOIN album al ON ai.album_id = al.id
INNER JOIN user us ON T.user_id = us.id
LEFT JOIN user_flickr uf ON us.flickr_id = uf.id
LEFT JOIN user_site uss ON us.user_site_id= uss.id
WHERE T.visible = in_image_visible
AND T.approved = in_image_approved
AND (T.advertise_to <= in_date_time_now OR T.advertise_to IS NULL) 
GROUP BY img.media_group_id;
```

I have tried to achieve the desired result in the image_media_group query above as i was thinking of changing the join in the main query to include this

Comment: Having Count(*) > 1...

Comment: yes but i want to bring back media groups that have one image- only a media group based on a distinct image_id where the having <=1. I want a random media group to be returned for each image_id where the count <=1

Comment: Oh misunderstood. Thought you were asking why where Count(*) > 1 didn't work.

Comment: please provide table structure and sample data using sqlfiddle